# NoReverseMatch at register - Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I'm trying to add an email confirmation feature to my django project.
I already created a view and a url, but i'm getting this error now:

```
Reverse for 'activate' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'MzA', 'token': '55y-fec02444935d88a056dc'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['activate/<uidb64:\\[0\\-9A\\-Za\\-z_\\\\\\-\\]\\+\\)>/<token:\\[0\\-9A\\-Za\\-z\\]\\{1,13\\}\\-\\[0\\-9A\\-Za\\-z\\]\\{1,20\\}\\)/\\$>\\)/$']
```

I think the error should be in the url, here it is:

```
path('activate/<uidb64:[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)>/<token:[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$>)/', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

Am i declaring it in a wrong way? Thanks in advance

Comment: You seem to mix `path` syntax with `url` syntax.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem could you show me the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [**`path`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#path) call looks like a mixture of typical `path` patterns, and [**`re_path`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path) (regular expression) syntax, making it very "strange".

You likely want to define something like:

```
from django.urls import re_path

# ...

re_path(r'^activate/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', views.activate, name='activate'),
```

So a call to [**`re_path`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urls/#re-path), and you define variables with `(?P<variablename>pattern)`.

Comment: Hey, i think re_path is for Django versions below 2.0.0. I'm using Django 2.0.0

Comment: No, it is part of Django-2.0 (this is a reference to the documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#re-path), note that Django-2.0 is outdated.

Comment: I'm getting a re_path() is not defined. Sorry, i just verified and i'm using 2.1.7

Comment: @Jack022: of course you need to `import` it at the top of your file, so `from django.urls import re_path`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it like this:

```
path('activate/<str:uidb64>/<str:token>/', views.activate, name='activate')
```

*(This section might not be relevant to your `noreversematch` error)*
Also, when you are going to use reverse, please ensure you are sending correct value for each keyword argument. From your question, I am assuming they are not correct(maybe the value of `token` belongs to `uidb64` and value of `uidb64` belongs to `token`). If so, then please call the reverse like this:

```
reverse('activate', kwargs={'token':'MzA', 'uid64': '55y-fec02444935d88a056dc'})
```

Or in urls:

```
{% url 'activate' token='MzA' uid64='55y-fec02444935d88a056dc' %}
```

Comment: When you use kwargs, the order of the items of the dictionary doesn't matter. The order only matters if you use `args`, e.g. `reverse('activate', args=[uidb, token])`.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. Maybe I was not clear enough in my answer. Updating it. Thanks.

Comment: The error message in the question says `with keyword arguments` - so the bit of your answer that says "I don’t think you sending them in correct order" doesn’t make sense

Comment: Yep, sorry I might have misread the question. Updated my answer accordingly. Thanks again for pointing out.